# I get "dpkg error" when I try to install anything

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I am constantly getting the following error message:

```
sudo apt install zoneminder
```

```
ERROR 1133 (42000) at line 1: Can't find any matching row in the user table
dpkg: error processing package zoneminder (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up zoneminder-doc (1.30.4-xenial1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zoneminder
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried the following to clean "1 not fully installed or removed"

1. ```
   sudo apt-get --force-yes remove zoneminder
   ```
2. ```
   apt-get autoremove
   ```
3. ```
   sudo apt-get -f install zoneminder
   ```

   (same dpkg error after)

Comment: The `Can't find any matching row in the user table` line looks like a MySQL (or similar) database query error. Also, could you please [edit] your question and include the complete output of your `apt` command, not just that snippet?

Comment: It is having problems connect to the mysql database, are you using msyql for other uses on this machine?

[upsteam source](https://github.com/ZoneMinder/ZoneMinder/blob/master/distros/ubuntu1604/zoneminder.postinst)

Answer (score 1):

```
dpkg --configure apt
```

That should do the trick.
It seems to me that your Package Manager isn't configured probably, And the command that is proposed above should do that.

Comment: I think you should explain you answer a little bit more, pointing to the source of the issue and why your command needs to be run.